# Installed Ubuntu to run along side of Windows 7, no option to boot Windows

Tags: 11.10, grub2

I have windows 7 but I wasn't satisfied, so I decided to try Linux Ubuntu.

I think I choose to run along side of Windows but since the install it will never give me the option to run Windows 7. Is there a code to put in terminal or can I check somehow to see if Windows os is still on my computer?

Please help me to where I can access Windows.

Comment: When you boot up, what screen do you get first?  Does the computer go straight into Ubuntu, or do you first get a text-only screen that lists Ubuntu (even if Ubuntu is on the only thing in the list)?  It's almost certain that your Windows is still there if you chose to install Ubuntu side by side with it.

Comment: Right after the BIOS post and before Ubuntu starts to load can you press <kdb>Shift</kbd> and check what are your boot options? Add that information to your question please.

Comment: @iSeth The answer here is reasonable. The OP asked for further information (which was never provided), but even as this is, this question will likely be useful to others. I recommend against closing this.

Answer (score 3):

If you can boot into Ubuntu, you might give Boot Repair a try.  I've used it several times and it works well.  Of course, it requires that you Windows stuff is still there, and it probably is.  The following text I copied from the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair):

Either add `ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` to your Software Sources via the Software Center or, for speeds-sake, add it using a new Terminal session:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
update sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Boot-Repair can be installed and used from any Ubuntu session (normal session, or live-CD, or live-USB). PPA packages are available for Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04.

Then:

Launch Boot-Repair from either :

- the Dash (Unity)
- System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Gnome)
- by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Then try "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, reboot and check if you recovered access to your OS.

Comment: the terminal command works but I'm a noob to the terminal thing and Linux. how do i get it to install as it should? what command do i tell it to give to install it properly? Should i install it if I'm not having boot problems?